# JS datatabe with Array edit

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

I has create HTML page, with user entry data in page then upload to SQL server.
I has study DataTable to load array to table, try edit still not , has any one can help?

```
var array = ['54 GR', '89 GR', 'Internal Transfer', 'Putaway']
```

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    data: array,
    "searching": false,
    columns: [{
        "data": 0,
        "title": "Date"
    }, {
        "data": 1,
        "title": "Account"
    }, {
        "data": 2,
        "title": "Type"
    }, {
        "data": 3,
        "title": "OPDeployed",
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {

            return "<input type='text' value=''/>";
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its really difficult to say without being able to see the page or even the code. All I can really say is that the load order should be:

jQuery
jQuery UI
DataTables
2 and 3 can be swapped and you shouldn't load more than one of each.